# Django - differences between using request.GET and request.POST

Tags: django, post, get, django-forms, request

From all the HTML books i've read, I know that POST should be used when changing, adding or removing from the database and when handling sensitive information like passwords. GET should be used when you just want to search through a database without making any changes. With that said, I am reading a book on Django and up until now, to handle forms, we did it like this:

```
def RegistrationFormView(request):
    form = RegistrationForm()
        if request.method == "POST": #if the user has clicked the 'submit' button on the form and is sending data
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
```

which makes sense. The book goes on to teach how to create a search page which searches through the database. For this, we use GET, which makes sense. This is the form:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(
    label='Enter a keyword to search for',
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 32})
)
```

But this is the view (and this is what confused me):

```
def search_page(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    bookmarks = []
    show_results = False #Only show results if the user has searched something
    if request.GET.has_key('query'): #check if the user submitted GET data
        show_results = True #return results since the user has submitted GET data
        query = request.GET['query'].strip() 
        if query:
            form = SearchForm({'query' : query})
```

I want to clarify four things here.

1) Would it be exactly the same if I just did

```
if request.method == "GET":
```

instead of

```
 if request.GET.has_key('query'):
```

2) in the line

```
if request.GET.has_key('query'):
```

according to the Djangobook, it says "has_key Returns True or False, designating whether request.GET or request.POST has the given key." Now, what exactly is a 'key'? Is a key a field in the form, and

```
if request.GET.has_key('query'):
```

checks to see if the user has filled out the formField which is called 'query'?

3) Am I allowed to call form.is_valid() when the method is GET? Because what I was thinking was doing

```
form = SearchForm(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():
    query = form.cleaned_data['query']
```

Is that allowed?

4) why does the book do

```
if query:
```

after

```
query = request.GET['query'].strip()
```

? Doesn't the line

```
if request.GET.has_key('query'):
```

already verify that the 'query' field is filled in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No. `if request.method == "GET":` is in no way equivalent to `if request.GET.has_key('query'):`
2. `request.GET` and `request.POST` are dictionary subclasses and `has_key` is part of the built-in dictionary interface http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key however it is deprecated in favor of `'query' in request.GET`.
3. Forms do not care about the request method or that there is a request at all. Forms validate dictionaries whatever the source might be.
4. In the case of `?query=` or `?query=%20` the key `query` would evaluate to `''` and `' '` which would both be `False` after running through `strip()`. `if request.GET.has_key('query'):` only checks that the key is present and does not look at the value.

Comment: okay thanks. For question #3, if I did "form = SearchForm(request.GET)
if form.is_valid():" then I wouldn't have to do "if request.GET.has_key('query'):" right? Because if form.is_valid() is true, then that means there definetely is a 'query' key since that's the only field the form has and form.is_valid checks and makes sure a 'query' is there, right? And as per your answer #4, if the key query='' or query=' ', even though it equals an empty string, it still exists right? So why would "if query:" evaluate to false even though it still exists?

Comment: Yes using `is_valid` already checks that the `query` argument was given and that it's a non-empty value. However `query = request.GET['query'].strip()` gets the value an then removes leading and trailing spaces. If `query` is only spaces then this will still evaluate to `False`. Really these check should all be in the form and not the view,